# How to get a percentage of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I'm wondering how to get a determined percentage of an array.

Let's say:

```
$array = array ("I","am","not","a","professional","coder","so","please","help","me");
```

It's composed of ten values.

I'd like to write a method to get a slice of it.

```
public function get_percentage($percentage) {...;return $array_sliced;}
```

So if I want an array containing only "I", I'd use

```
$this->get_percentage(10) //10 stands for 10%
//returns $slice = array ("I");
```

Also, it would be great if the $num could be rounded to the nearest useful value. E.g.:

```
$this->get_percentage(8) //8 stands for 8% but the function will treat this as 10%
//returns $slice = array ("I");
```

I didn't find any similar question here, hope this is not too complex.

Comment: *"hope this is not too complex"*: the best way to get a coder work for you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This method, using [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice), should do the trick for you:

```
public function get_percentage($percentage)
{
    $count = count($this->arr) * ($percentage / 100);
    return array_slice($this->arr, 0, round($count));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! You're the best!
Will this work even if the number has to be rounded? (last part of my question).

Comment: +1, but worth noting that array_slice truncates `$count`, so you'll need to [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) it first if you want 8% to return 1 element.

Comment: @Giorgio:  I just modified the code, so let me know if it now does what you need.